# How to get list of all materialized views in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to get list of all Materialized Views.?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  all_snapshots;
```

Instead of `all_snapshots` you can also use the `all_mviews` view.

Comment: [According to Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76961/ch276.htm), `ALL_SNAPSHOTS` is deprecated in favor of `ALL_MVIEWS`.

Answer (score 23):

```
select * from all_mviews;
```

or

```
select * from dba_mviews;
```

Comment: But... select * from Dba_Mviews is very slow. How to speed it up?

Answer (score 3):

I never use all_snapshots before.

Here is another way to do:

```
select * from all_objects where OBJECT_TYPE='MATERIALIZED VIEW';
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually ALL_MVIEWS and ALL_SNAPHOTS displays only the views the user has granted access  on. To see  all views in a database you must query DBA_MVIEWS or DBA_SNAPHOTS. You need special privileges or roles  to query this view like the system privilege SELECT ANY DICTIONARY or the role SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.
A similar statement holds for other  ALL_ and DBA_ views.