# Where is this Oracle object?

Tags: oracle, view

I have some SQL scripts; one of them references an object called "names".  I can:

```
select * from names
```

and it returns results.  However, I cannot see a table called "names".  Neither can I see a view called "names".  I can't find a custom type called "names".

If I look for one of the columns that is returned by the query `select * from names` using:

```sql
select * from sys.all_tab_columns where column_name like '%MyColumn%'
```

it finds a table called `LSNAMES`, but that has no rows.

Any ideas how I can find this "table"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start the research with understanding what type of object this is:

```sql
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
FROM   all_objects
WHERE  object_name = 'NAMES'
```

Once you have a type, you could query some more information from `all_<type>s`

Comment: Definitely the place to start. ALL_OBJECTS rather than USER_OBJECTS because it could be a public synonym.

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look for:

- A [materialized view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705306/how-to-get-list-of-all-materialized-views-in-oracle) called `NAMES`

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEWS WHERE MVIEW_NAME = 'NAMES';
  ```
- A synonym called `NAMES`

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM ALL_SYNONYMS WHERE SYNONYM_NAME = 'NAMES';
  ```